# what behavior will result while function returned but command in function is running in background?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Consider a shell script like this:

```
loop()
{
    while true; do
        sleep 10
        return 1
    done &

    return 0
}

loop
exit 0
```

The while clause is running in background, but function `loop()` was returned and the script was exited.

The `return 1` clause looks like a syntax error, but the console doesn't output any error message infact.

What behavior will result from this `return 1` clause?

EDIT:

Every command in script is running in child process(roughly), but my question is focus on `return 1` clause. This command should running in a function context, but while it run, the function context was destroyed. So behavior of this `return 1` clause is strange and unclear. Any idea?

Comment: Your `return 1` returns from the (part of the) `loop` function that has been backgrounded. There are no syntax errors whatsoever. In your case, it is strictly equivalent to: `f() { { sleep 10; return 1; } & return 0; }`.

Answer (score 2):

**Consider the following**

```
openvas:~$ vi test.sh
loop()
{
    while true; do
        sleep 10
        echo "1" 
        ps -fu openvas
        return 1
    done &

    echo "2"
    ps -fu openvas
    return 0
}

loop

echo "3"
ps -fu openvas
exit 0
```

**Results**

```
openvas:~$ sh test.sh 
2
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
openvas     13653 13603  0 16:22 pts/2    00:00:00 sh test.sh
openvas     13654 13653  0 16:22 pts/2    00:00:00 sh test.sh
openvas     13655 13653  0 16:22 pts/2    00:00:00 ps -fu openvas
openvas     13656 13654  0 16:22 pts/2    00:00:00 sleep 10
3
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
openvas     13653 13603  0 16:22 pts/2    00:00:00 sh test.sh
openvas     13654 13653  0 16:22 pts/2    00:00:00 sh test.sh
openvas     13656 13654  0 16:22 pts/2    00:00:00 sleep 10
openvas     13657 13653  0 16:22 pts/2    00:00:00 ps -fu openvas
1
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
openvas     13654     1  0 16:22 pts/2    00:00:00 sh test.sh
openvas     13658 13654  0 16:23 pts/2    00:00:00 ps -fu openvas
```

In the first ps output (echo 2), it is evident that when this script is invoked, bash assigns a PID 13653. which in turn assigns 13654 for the while loop.
Then sleep command is invoked with a PID 13656 from the parent 13654. ps command is called from the original script itself.

In the second ps output (echo 3), it is following the same pattern.

In the third ps output (echo 1), you can see that PID 13654 has a parent 1 instead of 13653. `This shows that init adopts this orphan.`
Since the parent process had already completed running and exited by the time the child checked for the parent's PID. This has caused the child to be re-parented under init, which has process ID 1.

In your case, the loop is not destroyed (PID 13654) once the script is exited with return 0, and it continues until it encounters return 1 which breaks it.

Comment: `return 1` certainly has an effect -- it aborts a loop which would otherwise be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop executes one time in an orphaned child process, then the child process ends.  Since the parent exited 10 seconds earlier, init "adopts" the process and reaps it.  In a sense you are making a zombie.

See what you get from this

```
loop()
{
    while true; do
        sleep 10
        return 1
    done &

    return 0
}

loop
ps
exit 0
```

Note the process running the sleep command - that is from the child process.

Comment: Every command in script is running in child process, but my question is focus on "return 1" clause. This command should running in a function context, but while it run, the function context was destroyed. So behavior of this "return 1" clause is strange and unclear.

Comment: A child process adopted by `init` is not a zombie, unless `init` for some reason never checks its exit status.

Comment: My point is, a zombie is a process that ends *before* its parent, but is never reaped. In this case, the child ends *after* the parent, requiring it to be adopted by `init`. Unless `init` fails to reap the process, you never create a zombie.